# How to efficiently find the max category total for n elements and m categories

Tags: java, arraylist

If I have an `ArrayList` of categorized items, for example Travel:

`Travel(String name, String distanceTraveled, String category)`

assuming that I want to know the `String category` in which there are the max  total of `distanceTraveled` (NOT the category of the single travel with the maximum `distanceTraveled`)

Initially my solution was to use a support list for each category, calculate the sum of the travel distance of each list, and  return the name of category with the max `distanceTraveled` sum.

But since I don't know how many categories there are, how could I do this **efficiently**?

Comment: @user35736644892
inefficiently you can add all categories ia another list, iterating the category list to see if already present and split the list in a separated list for each category. But this is a bad solution.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `HashMap<String, Double>` in which the key is the category and the value is the total distance for that category. You can loop over your list once, look up the appropriate key and accumulate the distance.

On that note, why is distance a string?

Comment: how to accumulate the distance separately for each key to do the comparison?